# Sum Numbers Input

Tags: python, algorithm, math, input, sum

I'm working on a simple python script that when run allows for an input of a number, then asks if another number input is wanted, if yes, the input entry is displayed, this is repeated until the answer is no when asked if another number input is needed.

Once "no" is entered, I need to sum all the numbers that were input and output it.

This part I have working, however, the issue I am facing is when the question is asked if another input is needed, if there is anything other than "Y"/"YES"/"N"/"NO" an error is displayed, in the summed output the error count is also being included and I can't quite figure out how to exclude the errors.

Here's the script:

```python
total = 0
num = 1
while num > 0:
    if num > 0:
        total = total + num
    cont = input("Would you like to enter another number: ").upper()
    if cont == "Y" or cont == "YES":
        float(input("Please enter number: \n"))
        continue
    if cont == "N" or cont == "NO":
        print("The total of the numbers is", total)
        break
    if cont != "N" and cont != "NO" and cont != "Y" and cont != "YES":
        print("Invalid response. Please enter Y or N")
        continue
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a lot going on here, but I've tried to refactor your code a bit to help you understand:

```
# Set up total:
total = 0

# Keep asking for numbers until we answer 'NO':
while True:
    # Ask user if they want to continue
    cont = input("Would you like to enter another number: ").upper()

    # If yes, get a number and add it to the total
    if cont == "Y" or cont == "YES":
        num = float(input("Please enter number: \n"))
        total += num
    # If no, print the total and break out of the while loop
    elif cont == "N" or cont == "NO":
        print("The total of the numbers is", total)
        break
    # Otherwise, try again.
    else:
        print("Invalid response. Please enter Y or N")
```

Comment: Thanks @CDJB, appreciate the detail & refactoring
When I run this update it still is summing the error results as well
Here's the results running this I would expect the result to be 3, but it's returning 4.

Would you like to enter another number:  y
Please enter number: 
 1
Would you like to enter another number:  dsfs
Invalid response. Please enter Y or N
Would you like to enter another number:  3
Invalid response. Please enter Y or N
Would you like to enter another number:  y
Please enter number: 
 2
Would you like to enter another number:  n
The total of the numbers is 4.0

Comment: Yes, I assumed this was the intended behaviour, sorry. To change this, just set num = 0 instead of 1 at the start of the code.

Comment: Awesome, that seems to be working as desired. Thank you so much!!